Wife escapes home and lives a gypsy-ish life
The poster shows a woman and a man passionately kissing!
I remember it was about a wife who escapes (or leaves) her family (probably in an airport) and then living a gipsy-ish life in some kind of cafe or motel, while the husband looks for her. The atmosphere was crowded and shabby, and reminded me of movies such as "The Bagdad Cafe" or "Underground".
I remember watching it about ten years ago, and it looked like an east European movie (I'm not so sure about this, it might have been an American film!). There were many funny moments, so it can be classified as a comedy. I remember one particular scene in which some of these men were taking a photo standing next to this (relatively high-class) woman and smiling, while one of them had an axe in his head!

You're looking for Montenegro from 1981.

Marilyn Jordan, an American, lives in Stockholm with her Swedish husband and family. Her behavior is bizarre, perhaps mad: she poisons the dog's milk and advises the dog not to drink it; she sets the sheets afire as her husband sleeps; she crawls under the dining table to sing. While detained at airport customs for carrying pruning shears, she meets a young Yugoslav woman and goes with her to a Gypsy enclave where she's fought over, takes a lover, helps with the sordid entertainment at a bar, and returns home more dangerous than before.

She poses for a picture in the airport with a man who has a knife stuck in his head, and the poster is exactly as you've described it:

